# Refreshing Combobox of Python Add-in of ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-addin, combo-box

I need to refresh the value in the combobox after an event from other tool in the same add-in (ARCGIS 10.1. Python).

I've changed the value of the combobox with the code:

```
combobox.value = val
```

and I want to show it in the combobox but I can't refresh this combobox after give a value in other tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As documented in the help, use the `.refresh()` method](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//014p00000024000000):

```
combobox.value = val
combobox.refresh()
```